# Button click change textview

Tags: java, android, textview, android-button

I want to make a simple counter program where I have a Textview and two buttons, one with + another with - whichever I press I get 1 incremented or decremented.

My problem is that I want the Textview to update a variable and not text. (By that I mean I get the app to work with `.setText("counter:"+ var_counter)` but doesn't work with `.setText(var_counter)`.

var_counter is an int.

```
    final TextView tvContador = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvContador);
Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bMais);
Button sub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bMenos);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           contador++;                                 
           tvContador.setText(getText(contador));
       }
});
```

p.s: my string is a resource string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `var_counter` is an `int`, `setText(var_counter)` tries to set the text of the widget to the string resource with such value as its *id*. What you want is:

```
setText(Integer.toString(var_counter));
```

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. Now i understand what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.setText(Integer.toString(var_counter));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
.setText(""+var_counter);
```

Comment: this answer would have been more helpful if you'd explained as well as shown. ie say why it works: tell us briefly about type coercion in your example, why the original version didn't work, etc.

Comment: If you concatenate integer value and string value together java converts it all to string variable. And I think it's simplier than do `Integer.toString(var_counter)`